# Performance of timescaledb with large datasets

Tags: timescaledb

we are considering using timescaledb and we would like to know if it is suited to storing timeseries of arrays of data. One example is we record 350 floats 4 times a second over months. We would then like to extract a few days or weeks of daya. A single entry is 350xfloats = 350x4 bytes = 1.4 kilobytes. A week's worth is 1.4x4x60x60x24x7 = 3.386 gigabytes.

How does timescaledb perform with such queries? Does anyone have experience storing and extracting timeseries datasets like this?

Thanks you for your feedback / suggestions.

Andy

Comment: TimescaleDB doesn't support data compression yet (it should be added in the next release), so you can hit disk IO bottleneck when query touches big amounts of data that doesn't fit RAM. Try using purpose-built time series databases with specialized data compression such as [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/). Thanks to good on-disk compression (by up to 70x comparing to TimescaleDB) they significantly reduce disk IO when working with big amounts of data.

Comment: Since V 1.5.x TimescaleDb has great [compression](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#compression) support

Answer (score 0):

TimescaleDB allows storing your data values in any format you prefer, the most optimal way to store data depends on your query pattern/requirements. Storing data as an array of floats is possible.